# Using one element across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have a navigation bar that I want to use across all pages so I can easily edit it once and have it update on all pages instead of changing each individually. How could I do this?

Would I created it in another html document and link the element to every page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<?php include ('filename.php') ?>` to include the same block of code on multiple pages.

Comment: So would I put the html code into the php file? Or am I missing something?